# El elemento body obedece al elemento div

Tags: html, css

Estoy empezando con css y html. Tratando de hacer algunas cosas me he encontrado con un comportamiento que no logro explicar. El elemento body tendría que estar cubriendo todo el elemento html porqué el padding de html es 0. Sin embargo al añadirle al elemento `<p>` un margen superior de 150px, el body se separa del elemento html y se distancia de arriba.
 Lo que no entiendo es porqué se distancia de arriba el margen del elemento `<p>`. Yo quisiera que el elemento `<p>` estuviera 150px separado del body, pero que el body no estuviera separado por arriba del html esos 150px. Si pongo en `<html>` padding : 0, y en `<body>` margin :0, esto tendría que resultar que el body está completamente pegado por arriba, igual que los esta por los lados.
Qué explicación tiene este comportamiento?
 Saludos

```
<style>
        html {padding :0px;
              background-color: red;
        }
        body {
            margin:0;
            background-color: green;
        }
        p{  margin : 150px auto;
            border: solid ;
            background-color: yellow;
            height: 250px;
            width: 400px;

        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <p> 1</p>
    <p> 2</p>
    <p> 3</p>
    <p> 4</p>
    <p> 5</p>
    <p> 6</p>

</body>
```

Comment: Al p quítale margin 150px y ponle 0px auto;

Comment: Gracias, Andy. Si pongo al p margin : 0 auto, entonces se me pega arriba de todo. Supongo que una solución sería derle al body un "padding" de x para que el p baje. Lo que no entiendo es porqué el body si tiene " margin: 0", y el html un padding:0, porqué el body obede a p cuando este toma un margen de x? Me interesaría entender el porqué.

Answer (score 0):

El body tiene un margen por defecto puedes documentarte un poco desde aqui https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

Al asignarle valores al html modificas lo que tiene por defecto.
Solo quita el css para el HTML y el body cubrirá todo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: green;
    }

    p {
      margin: 150px auto;
      border: solid;
      background-color: yellow;
      height: 250px;
      width: 400px;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>
  <p> 1</p>
  <p> 2</p>
  <p> 3</p>
  <p> 4</p>
  <p> 5</p>
  <p> 6</p>
</body>        
</html>
```

Puedes verlo funcionando aquí
https://plnkr.co/edit/2DRBHfDJTBFUacg0kdVa?p=preview

Comment: Gracias, Hugo. Después de buscar un buen rato no termino de encontrar una respuesta. Sí es cierto que si eliminamos los estilos de <html>, el <body> regresa al lugar esperado. Pero sin embargo, si mantenemos los estilos de <html> y en el elemento <body> le ponemos un contenido antes de los párrrafos, como: <body> CONTENIDO <p>1</p> ..... Entonces el <body> sí responde según las propiedades configuradas. Por lo tanto, el estilo de <html> no parece determinante.

Answer (score 0):

Seguí buscando y encontré donde está el problema.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168993/how-do-nested-vertical-margin-collapses-work.

La questión está en que entre dos contenedores si no hay una separación entre ellos, y los márgenes se tocan, entonces se produce el efecto conocido como "*collapcing*". Para que esto no suceda y cada uno se comporte "independientemente" se tienen que separar  los márgenes de alguna forma.
 Para separar los márgenes de dos contenedores, en este caso  `<body>` y `<p>`, se puede poner en el elemento exterior un padding, un border,algo de contenido, o también utilizar `overflow:hidden`. Probablemente este útlimo sea el más adecuado puesto que no tienes que añadir ningún padding o border, que en algún momento pueden molestar (aunque según como el overflow:hidden no me acaba de funcionar).

```
body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: green;
      padding : 1px;
    }
```

o tambén:

```
body {
          margin: 0;
          background-color: green;
          border: solid;
        }
```

Añado alguna cosa más que he encontrado y que es bastante importante saber sobre el comportamiento de las propiedads de background de `<html>` y `<body>`.

a)
https://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/

b)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body

Saludos.